# OS X Yosemite - My wired keyboard does not work anymore

Tags: keyboard, macos

I just downloaded OS X Yosemite Beta for testing  on my MacBook Air 11.

But my wired keyboard stopped to work.  Both the usb ports won't recognize the keyboard anymore.  I also tried to used even without the little USB extension cord that comes with the box.  any other idea do you have to make my WIRED APPLE KEYBOARD work again?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the exact same issue when I downloaded Yosemite.  I spent well over an hour with Applecare troubleshooting, PRAM resets, everything.  Tried all the different ports -- it was a mystery and they said I had to bring it to the store.  So I shut the computer down and brought it to the store a few days later, and miraculously the keyboard worked on the first start.  I felt like an ass.  Just this morning I downloaded the latest Yosemite update, and the exact same thing happened.  I tried all the proper troubleshooting as last time with the same non-results.  This time I said, let me shut my computer down for a few hours, unplug the keyboard, and basically simulate what I did last time at the store, but without the hassle.  Sure enough, I just restarted and re-plugged the keyboard in and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem after installing Yosemite(not beta but full release) and my corded keyboard is not recognized after boot up. Unplugging and replugging the keyboard forces the Mac to recognize the keyboard (so it is just a nuisance at this point) but I've noticed that a USB external drive keeps ejecting it's self. Perhaps there is a USB bug in Yosemite?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue myself using wired Apple keyboard (model A1243)on a late 2013 MacBook Pro Retina and running Yosemite 10.10.2.
Tried all resets above and power offer etc disconnecting all accessories,all to no avail.
Then tried a method from another site forum which suggested plugging a USB stick into one of the keyboard USB sockets.
Worked a treat.The Mac seems to find the USB stick and brings in the keyboard.
I have tried again without the USB stick and the keyboard doesn't fire up.
Seems to work this way every time.,so have left the stick in place which just has a few odd photo and data files on it.